# Ajax Call to WCF : Bad Request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-ajax

Getting Bad Request when calling a WCF method from an ASP.NET page using jquery. Am I missing something simple?

EDITED:

If I call a parameterless method it works fine. As soon as I try to send a parameter i get the Bad Request error.

```
var d = JSON.stringify({ control: 'usercontrol1' });
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:51926/CLAWPage.svc/LoadUserControl",
            type: "POST",
            data: d,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                jQuery('#placeholder').append(response); // or response
                $(".portlet").draggable();
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                jQuery('#placeholder').append(z);
            }
        });
```

Webservice method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string LoadUserControl(string control);
```

Webservice method implementation.

```
    public string LoadUserControl(string control)
    {
        using (Page _page = new Page())
        {
            //Load the user control
            UserControl usrControl = (UserControl)_page.LoadControl("Controls/" + control + ".ascx");
            //Set the name and age parameter values to User Control's respective labels
            _page.Controls.Add(usrControl);
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                _page.Controls.Add(usrControl);
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(_page, writer, false);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try `http://localhost:51926/CLAWPage.svc/LoadUserControl?control=" + d`

Comment: It must be showing failed `OPTIONS` request , let me know if this is the case, then I have a blog for that.

Comment: It's not "simple" per se...it really depends on what specific type of error and the "fix" varies quite a bit - e.g. Do you have some MVC routing going on? Is the service correctly configured - `webHttpBinding` ?...etc....

Comment: If I call a parameterless method it works fine. As soon as I try to send a parameter i get the Bad Request error.